# A generic method can use contravariant/covariant types?

Tags: c#, oop, generics, .net-4.0, t4

I'm writting a generalized method to use it in a special task at a T4 template. The method should allow me to use specialized types from a general interface. I thought about the following signatures:

```
interface IGreatInterface {
    Object aMethodAlpha<U>(U parameter) where U : IAnInterface;
    Object aMethodBeta(IAnInterface parameter)
}

public class AnInterestingClass : IAnInterface{}
```

When I try to implement `IGreatInterface` the compiler flags an error for `aMethodBeta()` because I've made my T4 to write that method using a subtype of `IAnInterface` (i.e. I want to implement that method like this: `Object aMethodBeta(AnInterestingClass parameter)`).

Method `aMethodAlpha<U>()` can be used but is not as clean as I want because my T4 has to generate some extra code. I (perhaps wrongly) 
propose that an implementation of that method, which has to be done by a T4, could be
`Object aMethodAlpha<AnInterestingClass>(AnInterestingClass  parameter)`.

I'm thinking that generic methods do not support contravariant types but I'm not sure; I suppose that It's the way the compiler prevents the coder to use a specific type having a method not defined in the general type...

1. Does a generic method have to use the exact type when being implemented?
2. Is there any trick to change this behavior?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.  Can you post the code that implements IGreatInterface and the specific compiler error?

Comment: @Juan: Just as a side note it helps to mark your updates with an *update* or something so we see what's changed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This question is quite confusing. Let me see if I can clarify it.

> When I try to implement `IGreatInterface` the compiler flags an error for `aMethodBeta()` because I've made that method using a subtype of `IAnInterface` I want to implement that method like this: `Object aMethodBeta(AnInterestingClass parameter)`.

That's not legal. Simplifying somewhat:

```
class Food {}
class Fruit : Food {}
class Meat : Food {}
interface IEater
{
    void Eat(Food food);
}
class Vegetarian : IEater
{
    public void Eat(Fruit fruit);
}
```

Class `Vegetarian` does not fulfill the contract of `IEater`. You should be able to pass *any* Food to Eat, but a `Vegetarian` only accepts Fruit. C# does not support *virtual method formal parameter covariance* because that is not typesafe.

Now, you might then say, how about this:

```
interface IFruitEater
{
    void Eat(Fruit fruit);
}
class Omnivore : IFruitEater
{
    public void Eat(Food food);
}
```

Now we have got type safety; `Omnivore` can be used as an `IFruitEater` because an `Omnivore` can eat fruit, as well as any other food.

Unfortunately, C# does not support *virtual method formal parameter type contravariance* even though doing so is in theory typesafe. Few languages do support this.

Similarly, C# does not support *virtual method return type variance* either.

I'm not sure if that actually answered your question or not. Can you clarify the question?

UPDATE:

What about:

```
interface IEater
{
    void Eat<T>(T t) where T : Food;
}
class Vegetarian : IEater
{
    // I only want to eat fruit!
    public void Eat<Fruit>(Fruit food) { }
}
```

Nope, that's not legal either. The contract of `IEater` is that you will provide a method `Eat<T>` that can take any `T` that is a `Food`. You cannot *partially* implement the contract, any more than you could do this:

```
interface IAdder
{
    int Add(int x, int y);
}
class Adder : IAdder
{
    // I only know how to add two!
    public int Add(2, int y){ ... }
}
```

However, you can do this:

```
interface IEater<T> where T : Food
{
    void Eat(T t);
}
class Vegetarian : IEater<Fruit>
{
    public void Eat(Fruit fruit) { }
}
```

That is perfectly legal. However, you cannot do:

```
interface IEater<T> where T : Food
{
    void Eat(T t);
}
class Omnivore : IEater<Fruit>
{
    public void Eat(Food food) { }
}
```

Because again, C# does not support virtual method formal parameter contravariance or covariance.

Note that C# *does* support *parametric polymorphism covariance* when doing so is known to be typesafe. For example, this is legal:

```
IEnumerable<Fruit> fruit = whatever;
IEnumerable<Food> food = fruit;
```

A sequence of fruit may be used as a sequence of food. Or,

```
IComparable<Fruit> fruitComparer = whatever;
IComparable<Apples> appleComparer = fruitComparer;
```

If you have something that can compare any two fruits then it can compare any two apples.

However, this kind of covariance and contravariance is only legal when all of the following are true: (1) the variance is provably typesafe, (2) the author of the type added variance annotations indicating the desired co- and contra-variances, (3) the varying type arguments involved are all reference types, (4) the generic type is either a delegate or an interface.

Comment: (Great answer! this comment will be used to clarify the question later...). Using your example: can I create a signature `IEater.Eat<T>(T food) where T : Food` and then implement `Omnivore.Eat<Fruit>(Fruit food)`? without the compiler flagging me for not implementing `IEater.Eat<T>(T food)`?. From your answer  I think it is not possible...

Comment: @JuanPabloContreras: I've added some additional text regarding your comment.

Comment: @EricLippert If possible could you please give your thoughts on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109478/process-address-space-vs-virtual-memory

Answer (score 2):

If you want to inherit from a generic interface, see phoog's answer.  If you are talking about trying to implement an interface co-variantly, that leads to my discussion below.

Assume:

```
internal interface IAnInterface { }

public class SomeSubClass : IAnInterface { }

public class AnotherSubClass : IAnInterface { }

public GreatClass : IGreatInterface { ... }
```

The problem with trying to implement the interface with a more derived (co-variant) argument is there's no guarante when this is called through an interface that an `IAnInterface` passed in will be a `SomeSubClass` instance.  This is why it's **not** allowed directly.

```
IGreatInterface x = new GreatClass();

x.aMethodBeta(new AnotherSubClass());
```

**IF** You could do covariance, this would fail because you would be expecting a `SomeSubClass` but would get a `AnotherSubClass`.

What you *could* do is to do explicit interface implementation:

```
class GreatInterface : IGreatInterface
{
    // explicitly implement aMethodBeta() when called from interface reference
    object IGreatInterface.aMethodBeta(IAnInterface parameter)
    {
        // do whatever you'd do on IAnInterface itself...
        var newParam = parameter as SomeSubClass;

        if (newParam != null)
        {
            aMethodBeta(newParam);
        }

        // otherwise do some other action...
    }

    // This version is visible from the class reference itself and has the 
    // sub-class parameter
    public object aMethodBeta(SomeSubClass parameter)
    {
        // do whatever
    }
}
```

Thus, if you did this, your interface supports the generic, the class has a more specific method, but still supports the interface.  The main difference is you'd need to handle the case where an unexpected implementation of `IAnInterface` is passed in.

**UPDATE**: it sounds like you want something like this:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    void SomeMethod<A>(A someArgument);
}

public class SomeClass : ISomeInterface
{
    public void SomeMethod<TA>(TA someArgument) where TA : SomeClass
    {

    }
}
```

This is not allowed, when you implement a generic method from an interface, the constraints must match.

Comment: hmmm... from your answer I can infer that .net doesn't accept subtypes with generic methods... Am I correct?

Comment: @Juan: I'm not sure what you mean by "doesn't accept".  Do you mean as arguments?  As parameter types?

Comment: @Juan: If you mean can I implement an interface but make the type more derived than the interface type?  No, you can't.  You can co-variantly, contra-variantly pass/return args, and you can co-variantly, contra-variantly assign interfaces and delegates (if marked appropriately), but not the implementation.

Comment: I'm talking about the type of the method. Suppose I've `aMethodAlpha<AType>(...)` in an interface. The implementation can be `aMethodAlpha<aDerivedType>(...)` where `aDerivedType : AType`? I concluded from your answer that this is not possible and the method implementation has to be `aMethodAlpha<aDerivedType>(...)`. If I'm correct you will get the check only by adding it to your original answer... thanks!

Comment: @Juan: So, you want the interface method to be generic, and the implementation of that interface method to give a more derived form of the generic type placeholder, correct?

Comment: @Juan: Okay, from re-reading your example, you're saying you want to plug in an ACTUAL sub-class as the generic type argument?  That is, have <T> in the interface and <ARealClass> in the class?  That cannot be done.

Comment: I want the first... "the interface method to be generic...". Sorry if I'm not clear, I think the question has to be rephrased...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for this:

```
interface IGreatInterface<in U> where U : IAnInterface
{ 
    Object aMethodAlpha(U parameter);
} 

class SomeClass : IAnInterface { /*...*/ }

class GreatClass : IGreatInterface<SomeClass>
{
    public Object aMethodAlpha(SomeClass parameter) {}
}
```

EDIT:

Yes, you are right: if you define a generic method in an interface, you can't implement that method with a concrete method using a compatible type.

How about using a delegate (since delegates support co- and contravariance):

[example deleted because I got the variance backwards -- it doesn't work.]